# Node with JWT Logout route, what do I need to pass on the body of the logout route?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm using this sample: https://github.com/jkasun/stack-abuse-express-jwt with Postman and all the routes works fine, minus the /logout

I'm passing the Bearer Token with the Token just like I did with the books.js Get and Post /books routes but I get the error:

"ReferenceError: t is not defined"

**I think I need to pass something on the body but I can't figure out what**

Route:

```
app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.body;
    refreshTokens = refreshTokens.filter(token => t !== token);

    res.send("Logout successful");
});
```

Comment: Guess it should be `(t => t !== token)`

Comment: @pzaenger Thanks for the help, Now I get "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable"

Comment: Is `refreshTokens` declared as `const`?

Comment: @pzaenger yes sir! Changed to let it works! Please post as and answer and I will accept as OK. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named the element of the callback of `filter` wrong. It should be `t`:

```
refreshTokens = refreshTokens.filter(t => t !== token);
```

In addition, to assign a new value to `refreshTokens` it must not be declared as `const`. You may want to use `let`.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in this. Let us tackle it. It is possible post will be long with all errors highlighting one by one to help you understand it. First you have to understand two differences accessTokens and refreshTokens, let me discuss it at end. First few corrections.

in your github file line `#22` you define following

```
const refreshTokens = [];
```

But it should be var or let not const as you will add more values in it. Constant is used not to change. Another thing you forget accessTokens to add here. So now modify it following

```
var refreshTokens = [];
var accessTokens = [];
```

On line number 35 you are creating access token, so also add it in this array by adding following after 38 beneath refereshTokens line

```
accessTokens.push(accessToken)
```

So all good you have saved both token, Now when you want to logout As per your coding seem you want to remove refresh token, as @pzaenger suggest do following.

```
refreshTokens = refreshTokens.filter((t) => t !== token)
```

This will remove your refreshToken, but your accessToken is still valide, there was not much functionality so not sure. Also you need to add your token in Headers as a Authorisation, not in Body.

Comment: thanks a lot, the repo is not mine, is from https://stackabuse.com/authentication-and-authorization-with-jwts-in-express-js/ . It's solved now :)

Comment: Oh ok, well writing tutorial is complicated stuff, so sometime mistake may happen with filter is actually a concise arrow function. I also started learning NodeJS so started to response on Stack overflow. this is my first response of NodeJS.